# A question regarding base change of a smooth algebra via completion

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, smoothness

Let $(R,m)$ be an excellent Noetherian local ring.  Let $S$ be a smooth (i.e. $R \rightarrow S$ is flat and has geometrically regular fibers) Noetherian $R$-algebra.  Let $T$ be the $m S$-adic completion of $S$.  Then by the universality of the tensor product construction, there is a natural map $\hat{R} \otimes_R S \rightarrow T$.  My question is: Does this map have to be flat?

Comment: Note that $T$ concides with the $m$-adic completion of the Noetherian $\widehat{R}\otimes_R S$, so the answer is positive.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger How do you know that $\hat{R} \otimes_R S$ is Noetherian?

Comment: "How do you know that $\widehat{R}\otimes_R S$ is Noetherian?" If $S$ is smooth over $R$, then $\widehat{R}\otimes_R S$ is smooth over the Noetherian ring $\widehat{R}$.  In particular, it is finitely presented over $\widehat{R}$.  Thus it is Noetherian by the Hilbert Basis Theorem.

Comment: @JasonStarr I see.  I guess this was a language problem.  By "smooth", I meant "flat, with geometrically regular fibers".  I am not assuming finite type.  I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Often such a map is called a "regular morphism".

Comment: With the current definition of "smoothness" (which I agree should be renamed regularity), the answer is easily no: take $S = \widehat{R}$, so $S=T=\widehat{R}$, but the map $\widehat{R} \otimes_R \widehat{R} \to \widehat{R}$ is usually not flat. For instance, if $R$ is the local ring of $\mathbf{A}^1$ at $0$, then this map is not flat. (For instance, one can see this using cotangent complexes, though it's probably more elementary than that.)

Comment: @Anonymous Perfect. Thank you!  Post it as an answer (along with your  demonstration of non-flatness) and I'll accept it.